# Is it possible to run session_destroy(); on a button click?

Tags: php

Is it possible to run `session_destroy();` on a button click?

I understand the usual use would be to create a page dedicated to it for example `logout.php` and link the button to that, but for simplicity is it not just possible to run it on a button click?

Comment: call `logout.php` file using ajax and put `session_destroy();` in the file

Comment: the button would need to make an AJAX request.  and then it could be done. (could still call logout.php in the backgroun)

Comment: A button click has to call some script to do the session_destroy() whether you call that script logout.php or session_destroy.php or nuke_it_from_orbit.php

Comment: Agreed - AJAX would be the way to go if you don't want to reload/load another page in the browser.

Answer (score 3):

Not directly. `session_destroy();` runs on the Server, your Button on the Client.

What you can do, is an Ajax call to `logout.php` on Button Click.

**Client:**

```
<script>
    $('#LogoutButton').click(function() {
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: "/path/to/logout.php",
            type: "GET"
        });

        request.done(function(msg) {
            alert("Logged Out");
        });

        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert("Error on Logging Out");
        });
    });
</script>
<button id="LogoutButton">Logout</button>
```

**Logout.php**

```
<?php
session_destroy();
?>
```

Regards

Comment: So it's not possible to do away with a separate `logout.php` at all?

Comment: On Clientside: No. Sure you can have simple in your code a part, to check if logout is required (for example `isset($_GET['logout']) { session_destroy(); }` and call your self with parameter `logout=1`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the AJAX answer, you could wrap the button in a `<form>` element, then have the form post to the same page. For example

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="logout" value="true" />
    <button>Logout</button>
</form>
```

Then in your PHP at the head of the document:

```
if(isset($_POST['logout'])) {
    unset($_SESSION[/*your user variables here*/ ]);
    session_destroy();
}
```

This would have to be at the head of every page, and is a little less neat than the AJAX answer because of that, but would do away with the need for a `logout.php` file

Comment: Have you tested this?

Comment: I have, my main concern is that it requires the user to navigate from the page for changes to take effect. I've updated the code with an unset before the destroy which fixes that issue. So long as this is called before any `$_SESSION` dependent code and after a `session_start()` and it should be fine